# Database field to MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for a way to use a field in a database as a query.  This is what I have:

**Column Title: banemail**

The contents of this field is updated using the vBulletin Settings page.  It stores the email addresses I want to ban from registering.  I need a query that will delete all users who are already registered and use a banned email. I want to retrieve the contents from the table, then use it a query of my own.

**Query so far:**

```
$datastoreemails = $vbulletin->db->query_read("SELECT data FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."datastore WHERE title = 'banemail'");

while($content = $vbulletin->db->fetch_array($datastoreemails))
  {
echo $content['data']."<br />";
  }
```

This output is:

> .cc .co hotmail

How can I then turn this output into a query to delete anyone in the database that has an email address containg the above?

This works when I run it manually but I have 20-30 banned email address and I would like to do it all in 1 query if possible.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_PREFIX_user WHERE email LIKE '%.com%';
```

TIA

Comment: Are `.cc`, `.co` and `hotmail` supposed to be considered three separate tokens for which the email records should be deleted?

Comment: Sorry, yes.  Banned emails are entered into the settings page seperated by a space.  I would enter the emails like this:

hotmail.com hotmail.co.uk gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used vbulletin so you may need ot adjust the below. I didn't know what the users table was for examples so I just entered "users".

```
    $datastoreemails = $vbulletin->db->query_read("SELECT data FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."datastore WHERE title = 'banemail'");

    //Create an array of banned emails.
    $bannedEmails = [];
    while($content = $vbulletin->db->fetch_array($datastoreemails))
    {
        //Explode your data by a space to return an array of items you are looking for
        $bannedEmails = array_merge($bannedEmails, explode(" ", $content['data']));
    }

    //check if there is anything in the banned Emails, if so build your "delete" query
    if(is_array($bannedEmails) && count($bannedEmails) > 0) :

        $deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users WHERE";

        $deleteWhere = "";
        //Loop through the array adding each email stub in to the query
        foreach($bannedEmails as $email):

            //If this is the second time through the loop add the AND clause
            if($deleteWhere != "") $deleteWhere .= "OR ";

            //Add in where email like %hotmail.com% to match anything that looks like it.
            $deleteWhere .= " email like '%" .$email . "%' ";
        endforeach;

        //Add the where on the end of the query
        $deleteQuery .= $deleteWhere;

        //Now all you need to do is execute the delete, I'm just going to print it out so you can check the
        //sql first!
        echo $deleteQuery;
    endif;
```

From your code it looks like there is a single text field which will hold the banned email addresses in your database. If that is the case then you might want to use "query_first" like this $vbulletin->db->query_first($query) as that will just pull one row out, and you won't have to loop through the results. I've written the code above in case there are multiple rows with banned emails in, which should work even if there is just one.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, you are correct, the content is stored in just 1 text field.  I will let you know how I get on with this.

Comment: The echo puts out exactly what I want but the query is not being exectued by sql.  I even tried it directly in phpmyadmin and this is what I got.

`0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0015 seconds.)
DELETE FROM tf_user WHERE email like '%i.com%' AND email like '%hello%'`

Comment: Sorry, change the AND for an OR. It's obviously not working as there are no rows that match HELLO and i.com.... In production make sure you use "@i.com" otherwise bini.com and benni.com or anything that ends with a i.com will be matched. Same with using words, it will match any email with those parts in it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the reult of select fro delete directly

assuming you have

```
  SELECT data FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."datastore WHERE title = 'banemail'"
```

then you could

```
("DELETE 
  FROM " .TABLE_PREFIX ."user 
  WHERE email in (   SELECT data 
      FROM " .TABLE_PREFIX."datastore 
      WHERE title = 'banemail'" );
```

Comment: When I run this via a plugin, I get an error:
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'SELECT' (T_STRING) in /global.php(29) : eval()'d code on line 3

Comment: show me the exact error message  .. and if you can update your question adding the exact you are using  .. comment me when done

Comment: `Database error in vBulletin 4.2.3:

Invalid SQL:
DELETE 
  FROM tf_user 
  WHERE email in (   SELECT data 
          FROM tf_datastore 
          WHERE title = 'banemail';

MySQL Error   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
Error Number  : 1064
Request Date  : Thursday, January 26th 2017 @ 04:13:28 PM
Error Date    : Thursday, January 26th 2017 @ 04:13:28 PM
Classname     : vB_Database
MySQL Version : 5.5.52-MariaDB`

Comment: @John   answer  updated  but  you should check for the correct sintax of TABLE_PREFIX   concat